# OracleParameter works with value larger than size defined

Tags: c#, oracle, parameter-passing, oracle12c

This is an older project from some years ago that just experienced a production problem.
In the code, it's building up OracleCommand object and adding OracleParameters to it.

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(Settings.ConnectionString))
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("STORED_PROC_NAME", con))
{
   con.Open();
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   //adding some params

   cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("IN_NODE_IDS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 8)).Value = string.Join(",", nodeIds);

   //adding more params

   using (OracleDataReader odr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

`nodeIds` is a list of strings where every string used to be up to 6 digits long.  So, for example, the value of `IN_NODE_IDS` could have been:

```
    876345
   or
    876345,873635,736353
```

Now, notice the size parameter passed to OracleParameter constructor.  It's 8.  Both examples from above used to work just fine!

Node ids are auto incremented values that come from the database. A few days ago, they reached 999999 and so the next inserted record got it's id of 1000000.  And that's when the call to stored proc started to fail.

So, as far as I thought I knew, such a case as

```
876345,873635,736353
```

should've failed before, but it worked fine.
Now, something like

```
1000025,1000026
```

blows up the stored proc.

Increasing the value of the size parameter to something like 4000 works fine and seems to solve the problem.  But I just don't understand how it worked all these years.

One more thought. The way I understood the size parameter is that it cuts off the value if the value is longer than the size. So the size of 8 would turn 6 digit ids `876345,873635,736353` into `876345,8`. If the first id is 7 digits long, then the comma would end up as the last character and somehow cause a problem.  But, bumping the size up to 9 did not work for 7 digit ids.

Oracle.DataAccess (unmanaged) DLL version 4.112.1.2.

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

**EDIT:**

As been suggested in the comment below, I looked inside the stored proc.
The only line where it makes use of `IN_NODE_IDS` looks like this.

```
'AND cm.node_id IN (' || in_node_ids || ') ' ||
```

Where in_node_ids (lowercase) is the Varchar2 that gets the value of multiple ids joined by comma.

Comment: Please post actual stored procedure or at least the part where you parse varchar2 parameter CSV. You probably have hardcoded splitting by 6/7 digits and that is causing problem.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda please look at the EDIT.  Thanks.

Comment: So it looks like you are using dynamic SQL inside stored procedure. I propose to debug query with different inputs. For example `SELET * FROM tab WHERE cm.node IN (1000025,)` is incorrect.

Comment: I would agree! So following this logic, if I increase the size parameter in C# code from 8 to 9, then `SELET * FROM tab WHERE cm.node IN (1000025,1)` would be fine.  But it blows up.

Comment: Furthermore, with size 8, 'cm.node IN (999976,9)` should produce a different result from 'cm.node IN (999976,999977,999978,999979,999980)`.  But it doesn't! It works fine.

Comment: Can you test the stored proc locally passing in the values of `1000025,1000026` whats the result?  I am confused though because this `and cm.node_id in (' || in_node_ids || ')'` will look for one record with a node_id of `1000025,1000026` rather than any with either of those codes - why use IN?  Very confusing